# Deleting duplicates words and phrases within a cell

Tags: vba, excel

My spreadsheet has a column which can have multiple word or phrase duplicates within a cell.

Here is an example of the type of values:

```
╔════════════════════════╗
║        Column A        ║
╠════════════════════════╣
║ Apple                  ║
║ Apple Apple            ║
║ Apple Pie              ║
║ Apple Pie Apple Pie    ║
╚════════════════════════╝
```

I am looking for the best way to delete duplicate values within a cell. Is there any known  VBA code or excel formulas I could use?  It would need to recognize a either duplicate words or phrases (up to 3 words) The spreadsheet is large and would be a pain to go and manually remove them.

Any ideas , solutions or direction would be great.

Comment: what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex with a backreference to match duplicated words or phrases. The pattern `^(.+)\s*\1$` will match any duplicating phrase with optional whitespace in between.

```
Const strText = "Apple Pie Apple Pie"

Dim re
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Pattern = "^(.+)\s*\1$" 

If re.Test(strText) Then
    Debug.Print re.Replace(strText, "$1")
End If
```

Output:

```
Apple Pie
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use an Excel function that finds and deletes MOST of the duplicate Names and phrases within the cell. Hope this helps others

```
 =IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))>=2,LEFT(A1,FIND(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)-1),A1,2)-2),LEFT(A1,FIND(" "&LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),A1,2)-1))
```